# Express res.json doesnt end

Tags: express, serverless

I have the code in express, serverless-http and AWS:

```
  res.status(404).json({ error: `Usuario ${userId} no encontrado`, _uuid: req._uuid });
  console.log("No se encontró nada < End ");
```

When i send res.status(404)... it sent and show in console the message. Why?

Comment: `res.json` will just send the response, didn't end the function, the code below it will still be executed. You should put `return` in front of `res.json` to prevent it

Answer (score 1):

`res.send`, `res.json`, `res.end` just finish the http request by send a response (`send`, `json`) or end it (`end`). It doesnt end your code flow (in this case maybe inside a function). To finish your function after send the response `res`, simply add `return` in front of it:

```
return res.status(404).json({ error: `Usuario ${userId} no encontrado`, _uuid: req._uuid });
console.log("No se encontró nada < End "); // no longer execute this line
```

Sometimes this behavior will allow you to do some work after sending back the http response, like update database, write some log, etc but it rarely uses.